# How can we select data from another table during an insert?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data into a table using a few columns that are hard-coded or are static values and then the rest of the datat selected from another table. I've tried the following query:

```
insert into wtdocversion 
values (( select id from wtdocmaster),'col2','col3');
```

But this generates an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 6):

You want to drop the `values` part of the query and do an `INSERT\SELECT`.

This is really basic SQL and you can read more about it in [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
INSERT INTO wtdocversion (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT
  id,
  'col2',
  'col3'
FROM wtdocmaster;
```